# Can't work with swing UI within applet - calling public method

Tags: java, javascript, swing, applet, japplet

My problem is as follows:  I have a `JApplet` embedded into the HTML page and a `form`  button with JS call of applet's public method:

```
<input id="btnAppletSelectFiles" type="button" value="Select Files" 
    onclick="document.appletExcelUploader.SelectFiles();" />
```

in my JApplet I have FileChooser like:

```
public class ExcelUploader extends JApplet {

    private JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    // Some stuff
}
```

And I'm writing code like this in my applets' public method:

```
  public void SelectFiles() {
        int retVal = fc.showOpenDialog(ControlsPanel.this);

        if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            for (File file : fc.getSelectedFiles()) {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

And so when HTML button is clicked, File Dialog is shown normally, I can surf directories and check files, but I cannot press <kbd>Open</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd> button - I click it but dialog stays.

I think that I have a problem with threads - that I still somehow do this in "HTML and JS" Thread and not in my applets' GUI thread or event dispatch thread.

How to fix the problem?

Comment: But if I just add a button inside applet and call dialog from there everything is ok.

Comment: - Applet upload works as it is with java code signed or not
- JS browser thread accesses applet with UI and it stops working
- Applet is executed in a browser thread
- If browser security is the same for all threads which seems logical, problem is with inter-thread communications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods in trusted applets that are called from JavaScript are no longer trusted because Java cannot account for all the code frames in the stack.  To rectify the problem, use one of the [`AccessController.doPrivileged(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#method_summary) overloaded methods.

Comment: Thanks, code looks rather strange but it works now

`AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>() {

            public String run() {
                try {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            controls.selectFiles();
                        }

                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                return "42";
            }

        });`